# XML output using oracle sql

Tags: oracle

Please guide me how to get below output using oracle sql query and output should be in one row and one column(single row column).

```
<Row><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SMITH</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">800</Data></Cell></Row> <Row><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ALLEN</Data></Cell><Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1600</Data></Cell></Row>
```

---

i tried using sql statement but i'm getting multiple rows.

```
select 
'<Row>'||XMLELEMENT("Cell",XMLELEMENT("Data",xmlattributes('String' as  "ss:Type"),ename) )||
  XMLELEMENT("Cell",XMLELEMENT("Data",xmlattributes('String' as  "ss:Type"),sal)) ||'</Row>' as "Result" from emp;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the XML using the standard package **DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML**.

**Note:-**

You should have sufficient privilege to run the package. If you are using Oracle local database with admin access, you shouldn't have any problem.

**Syntax:-**

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(Your select query here) from dual;
```

**Example:-**

```
SELECT dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select first_name, last_name, phone_number, email from employees where employee_id in (100,101)')
FROM dual;
```

If you need only one row in output, you can use **rownum = 1** in where clause to limit the number of rows in the output.

[Convert SQL result to XML using standard package](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_xmlgen.htm)

Comment: OP seems to need attributes as well. Does your example support this case?

Comment: It doesn't return the attribute type. However, DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE generates the XML document and returns it as a sys.XMLType. I believe you don't need a type in output as XML as its own type. You can define a schema (XSD) and consume the data in other process.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`XMLAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) to aggregate the rows:

```
SELECT  XMLAGG(
          XMLELEMENT(
            "Row",
            XMLELEMENT(
              "Cell",
              XMLELEMENT("Data",xmlattributes('String' as  "ss:Type"),ename)
            ),
            XMLELEMENT(
              "Cell",
              XMLELEMENT("Data",xmlattributes('String' as  "ss:Type"),sal)
            )
          )
        ).getClobVal() AS "Result"
FROM    emp;
```